# Combining formulas that has changing quantities

Tags: excel, formula, price

I have created 9 different formulas, but I want to make all them one formula. I work in a retail shop, once the quantity is over 12 the prices change, and for 24,36,48...I am trying to make a formula where when I put in the quantity of items and it changes the price to the correct price for that quantity.

This is the formula for 12: =(C6*1.6)+(C7*11.65)+(C8*2.55)+(C9*2.75)+(C10*2.75)

This is the formula for 24: =(F6*1.6)+(F7*7.25)+(F8*2.3)+(F9*1.55)+(F10*1.55)

This is the formula for 36: =(I6*1.6)+(I7*5.55)+(I8*1.8)+(I9*1.05)+(I10*1.05)

[Here is what the spreadsheet looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xJ8pw.png)

Answer (score 0):

First remove the multipliers to cells:

```
eg 
M  - N   - O     - P    - Q    -  R 
12 - 1.6 - 11.65 - 2.55 - 2.75 - 2.75
24 - 1.6 - 07.25 - 2.30 - 1.55 - 1.55
etc
```

then update the multipliers to vlookups:

eg for =(C6*1.6)+(C7*11.65)

change to (note: I've called it "quantity" as I'm not sure the cell reference, replace this with your quantity cell ref)

```
=(C6* vlookup("quantity",M:R,2,false))+(C7* vlookup("quantity",M:R,3,false)) + etc
```

if you have values that might not always be whole numbers divisible by 12 then replace "quantity" in the vlookup with:

```
Roundup("quantity"/12,0)*12
```

so the entire formula would look like:

```
=(C6* vlookup(Roundup("quantity"/12,0)*12,M:R,2,false))+(C7* vlookup(Roundup("quantity"/12,0)*12,M:R,3,false)) + etc
```

---

Edit:

Thanks for the updated picture and information:

This formula should work if you copy it into cell C10.

```
=(C6* VLOOKUP(ROUNDUP(C5/12,0)*12,I:N,2,FALSE))+(C7* VLOOKUP(ROUNDUP(C5/12,0)*12,I:N,3,FALSE))+(C8* VLOOKUP(ROUNDUP(C5/12,0)*12,I:N,4,FALSE))+(C9* VLOOKUP(ROUNDUP(C5/12,0)*12,I:N,5,FALSE))+(C10* VLOOKUP(ROUNDUP(C5/12,0)*12,I:N,6,FALSE))
```

---

based on working on a range:

you will need to update your sheet to match the following:

[image: image of required layout]

Range Low - Range High are the range of numbers eg 0-23 24-35, Row name is just a list of unique characters.

Then into cell `F2` put the following formula:

```
=INDEX(I2:I20, SUMPRODUCT(--($C$6<=H2:H20), --($C$6>=G2:G20), ROW(F1:F19)))
```

- for more information on how this works see: [Link](http://www.get-digital-help.com/2010/01/13/return-value-if-in-range-in-excel/)

Then into cell `C13` add the following formula:

```
=(C7* VLOOKUP(F2,I:N,2,FALSE))+(C8* VLOOKUP(F2,I:N,3,FALSE))+(C9* VLOOKUP(F2,I:N,4,FALSE))+(C10* VLOOKUP(F2,I:N,5,FALSE))+(C11* VLOOKUP(F2,I:N,6,FALSE))
```

---

This will allow you to change the prices and the ranges as you need.

Comment: Thank you so much @delta_zulu, I think I am starting to understand it all. For "range of multipliers" what do I put there? Do I put 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11?

Comment: @kbut I've updated the formula, the "range of multipliers' should have read M:R from my first statement to move the multipliers to cells.

Comment: I am really new to excel when it comes to complicated formulas. I don't really know what I am doing, but is this close?                                                                                                                                                                             =(C5* VLOOKUP(ROUNDDOWN(I1/12,0)*12,I:N,2,FALSE))+(C6* VLOOKUP(ROUNDDOWN(J1/12,0)*12,I:N,3,FALSE))+(C7* VLOOKUP(ROUNDDOWN(K1/12,0)*12,I:N,3,FALSE))+(C8* VLOOKUP(ROUNDDOWN(L1/12,0)*12,I:N,3,FLASE))+(C9* VLOOKUP(ROUNDDOWN(M1/12,0)*12,I:N,3,FLASE))+(C10* VLOOKUP(ROUNDDOWN(N1/12,0)*12,I:N,3,FLASE))

Comment: I also posted a picture in my original question of what the spreadsheet looks like.

Comment: @kbut awesome, i'll get back to you shortly.

Comment: @kbut I've update the answer for you. Can you give that a try?

Comment: And yes you were very close, where you had 3 in each vlookup you should have had 2-6 for each column you wanted to return, eg for quantity 1; 2 returns 1.6, 4 returns 2.55 etc

Comment: it works great, there is just one little tweak I need. If someone buys an item quantity from 1-23 it is the 12 item price, if you buy 24-35 it's the 24 price, if you buy 36-47 it is the 36 price, if you buy 48-71 its the 48 price. If you buy 72-143 it is the 72 price, if you buy 144-287 it is the 144 price, if you buy 288-499 it is the 288 price and finally if you buy 500 or more it is the 500 price. I'm sure this is a pretty easy fix, but I don't know how to do it. Thank you again so much.

Comment: I'm not sure if you saw that I posted again, if you did I apologize I will wait patiently since you are my life saver @delta_zulu

Comment: @kbut Work got in the way of replying yesterday, thanks for following up. I've edited my answer again to suit.

Comment: @kbut did this work? is there anything else you need help with. If it's worked can you tick it as answered?

Comment: Thank you so much! I have been really busy at the shop and I have just put this project on the back burner. It worked great! You're amazing and I am forever indebted to you. @delta_zulu

Comment: How do I check the question off as answered? @delta_zulu

Comment: Did you need any further help with this @kbut?